# Bootstrap How to stick the navigation bar on top when scroll down the webpage

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-3.3.7-dist. Does anyone know how to stick the navigation bar on top when scroll down the webpage?? Please help.

Here is the HTML code.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#business_register">Register</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">

      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Management <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#upload_product">Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sort_product">Sorting</a></li>
        <li><a href="#permission_management">Permission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#communicate">Communication</a></li>
        <li><a href="#basic_information">Information</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Just scroll content but menu.

```css
#content{
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;  
}

body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="content">
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p><p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p><p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
<p>sadsad</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the id #navbar-static-top and ensure the template is nested how bootstrap needs it

getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-static-top